# How to make POST multipart/form-data request from Next.js 14 server action

Tags: next.js

I'm using [node-fetch](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch) and [form-data](https://github.com/form-data/form-data#node-fetch) to POST a `multipart/form-data` to upload a file to an external endpoint. Here are the back-end code snippet:

```js
import fs from "fs";
import FormData from "form-data";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

...
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("uploadFile", fs.createReadStream("playground.pdf"));

await fetch("https://...", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: formData.getHeaders(),
  body: formData,
});
```

The above code is working without problem.

I'm trying to migrate the above code to server action in Next.js, and Next.js 14 [extends the native Web fetch() API](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/fetch). Does it still make sense to use `node-fetch` while there is an extended fetch() API available?

From Google, almost all the examples are using `node-fetch` and `form-data` libraries.

Can we make a POST `multipart/form-data` request using `fetch()` API instead of `node-fetch` and `form-data` libraries in Next.js 14?

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, we can send a POST multipart/form-data using `fetch()` API like this,

```js
const buffer = fs.readFileSync("playground.pdf");

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("uploadFile", new Blob([buffer]), "playground.pdf");

await fetch("https://...", {
  method: "POST",
  body: formData,
});
```

It looks simpler than without using the libraries.

Comment: this works on client, but not working on server